# Sublime text 3 plugin to get JSON path

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, sublimetext3, jsonpath, sublime-text-plugin

I am after a plugin or technique in sublime text 3 to get what I will call the fully qualified path of the json element that is selected in the editor window.

Somethink like: http://jsonpath.com/

I want to get a result somewhere that I can copy, I just want to use this for documentation, not programmatically. It does not need to be the https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath standard, just something that produces a readable/meaningful path to an element.

Comment: Are you looking to get a full path to the current cursor location in the json file, or are you looking to get results based on an object query from an input panel? [**JsonTree**](https://github.com/Flyclops/JsonTree) has some [**code**](https://github.com/Flyclops/JsonTree/blob/master/JsonTree.py) that you might be able to rework into a solution. Maybe create two additional arrays in parallel with `keys` & `trimkeys`, one that contains regions & another that contains the object's path.

Comment: I am after the "full path to the current cursor location in the json file". Will have a look at your suggestion, thanks.

Comment: @MattG did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @sakurashinken, I switched to [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), which I prefer now anyway, and also use this extension: [JSONPath StatusBar](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=richie5um2.vscode-statusbar-json-path)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For those who came here looking for ST3 implementation of jsonpath, there's an awesome [Pretty JSON](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Pretty%20JSON) plugin.

[image]

It has [jQ](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) integration, which does the same same thing as jsonpath. jQ has different syntax, but it's much more convenient to have this functionality available inside ST3 than to switch to browser.

Comment: [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/) should be installed manually; for Linux use command *sudo apt-get install jq*

Comment: This is working on Windows, too. Simply download jq.exe and save to a directory in path.

Comment: It's been already 2 years since there's a [JQ plugin for Sublime](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Jq). It's even more convenient than PrettyJSON.

Answer (score 12):

I was searching for the same and ended up creating a plugin myself: https://github.com/akirk/StatusBarJsonPath

[image: screenrecording of StatusBarJsonPath]

Comment: Update: you can now get it via https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Status%20Bar%20JsonPath